# Persisting web service passwords

Tags: java, encryption, passwords, web-services

I'm not a security guy so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

I have a large number of third-party field devices that have remote methods that can be called across xml-rpc using ssl. For each method call, a username and password must be transmitted in plain text as parameters along with any other method parameters. I have no control over the devices or their implementation.

I'm currently writing a web application that a user would log into and then have access to some number of those field devices. The user doesn't need to know what devices they are connecting to, they just need the data. As such, I need to persist the username and password for each device in a database where they can be retrieved when an rpc call needs to be made.

How do I encrypt my device service passwords so that they can be decrypted when a call needs to be made? How do I decrypt the password when a call needs to be made?

I'm using Java and Spring for the application.

Note, I am not asking how to persist the user's login password.

Comment: Fun problem :) Would each user have their own user id\password per device, is there a "system defined" user id\password per device or is it a combination?

Comment: Each device would have one username-password pair which would be used for each xml-rpc call made regardless of the user logged into the web application.

Answer (score 1):

If I have this right, there is only one username/pswd per field device (though each is different and there are many field devices).

Build a secure proxy service with access to all device passwords. The device passwords can be stored encrypted with proxy service's public key. Your web app presents user key to proxy service which (assuming satisfied) talks to field devices on their behalf. CryptoApi or one of its wrappers should be all you need.

You don't comment on numbers, but given proxy would be stateless, it should scale ok.

Answer (score 0):

We solved similar problems with [this code](http://github.com/olas/bioclipse.core/blob/master/plugins/net.bioclipse.encryption/src/net/bioclipse/encryption/Encrypter.java).

You would use the password the users log into your web application with as key when encrypting the usernames and passwords for the other services.

Comment: Each service has one username/password pair. There is a many-to-many relationship between users and the services they will access. So I can't use one user's password to encrypt the service username and password because another user will most likely need access to that service.